# plesk use specific directory as root for website

Tags: plesk, document-root, plesk-onyx

I got used to have all my websites in /var/www so no matter which domain, each subdomain has its document root located in /var/www/

Plesk is trying to force me to use /var/www/vhosts/domain/ and I did not find a way to tell Plesk to just put everything into /var/www.

I don't want a whole new structure, I want to migrate my existing websites from my old server (without Plesk) to my new server running Plesk 17.8

Edit: Feel free to answer this question for future reference but I won't need it as I realized that no sane person would use Plesk. Server will be reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213367009-How-to-change-virtual-hosts-location-in-Plesk-for-Linux) may help you:

In Plesk for Linux, `transvhosts.pl` utility can be used to change the location for all virtual hosts:

```
# /usr/local/psa/bin/transvhosts.pl --help
```

In the following example, the location is changed to `/home` directory:

```
# /usr/local/psa/bin/transvhosts.pl --dest-dir /home --correct-scripts
```

Note, that currently Plesk Onyx with SELinux enabled does not support custom vhosts directory.

Comment: You can change vhosts location with Plesk transvhosts.pl utility.